# Android widget listview handle click

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget

I have seen related questions for this issue but I'am unable to figure out why this is not working for me.

I am expecting for onReceive() method in Widget Provider class to be called as the list item is clicked, but nothing happens.

Some comments are included, and they show what I have been trying as well.

Relevant code:

Main app layout has ListView defined like this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/events_list"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Row is defined with RelativeLayout with two nested Linear layouts, not sure if this is important to share.

getViewAt() is implemented through view factory and here's the function:

```
@Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        if (events_ack == null) {
            Log.e("LIST", "getViewAt (null) events_ack");
            return null;
        }

        RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);

        row.setTextViewText(R.id.event_name, events_ack[position].name);
        row.setTextViewText(R.id.description, events_ack[position].description);
        row.setTextViewText(R.id.publicTV, (events_ack[position].is_public == 0) ? "Public: False" : "Public: True");
        row.setTextViewText(R.id.timeTV, events_ack[position].time);
        row.setViewVisibility(R.id.price, View.GONE);

        // download and set image BONUS QUESTION- does not work through AsyncTask using future insted (images are downloaded but not shown).

        row.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, pic);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(CasusWidgetProvider.EXTRA_WORD, events_ack[position].id);
        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
        // Make it possible to distinguish the individual on-click
        // action of a given item
        row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.events_list, fillInIntent); 

        //extras.putInt(CasusWidgetProvider.EXTRA_WORD, events_ack[position].id);
        //i.putExtras(extras);
        //i.setAction(CasusWidgetProvider.ITEM_CLICK);
        //row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.layout.casus_widget, i); //event_name?

        // ??

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.casus_widget);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
        //appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, row);

        return row;
    }
```

Widget Provider class has onUpdate() method:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.w("CASUS", "UPDATE function called");


        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.casus_widget);
            rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.events_list, intent);

            Intent clickIntent=new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            clickIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            clickIntent.setAction(ITEM_CLICK);

            PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.events_list, clickPI);
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i],  R.id.events_list); //?

            clickIntent = new Intent(context, CasusWidgetProvider.class);
            clickIntent.setAction(UPDATE_LIST);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);


            PendingIntent pendingIntentRefresh = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, 0);
            rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntentRefresh);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
        }

        fetchData(context, appWidgetIds);

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. onUpdate() function in widget provider class was modified to look like this:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.casus_widget);
            rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.events_list, intent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
        }

        fetchData(context, appWidgetIds);

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }
```

In getViewAt() function on widget factory this line:

```
row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.events_list, fillInIntent);
```

Was modified to match correct ID:

```
row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.row_layout, fillInIntent);
```

The click handler template is set in class that does the HTTP request, basically:

```
for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.casus_widget);


            Intent svcIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), WidgetService.class);
            svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
            svcIntent.putExtra("events", events);
            svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(widgetId, R.id.events_list, svcIntent);


            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), CasusWidgetProvider.class);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, allWidgetIds);
            clickIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            clickIntent.setAction(CasusWidgetProvider.ITEM_CLICK);


            PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.events_list, toastPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

        }
```

Hope this might help..